# Cannot convert lambda expression & The name '_' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

Can anybody help me to fix it?
i've got 2 type error message

1. The name **'closure_'** does not exist in the current context
2. Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Delegate' because
       it is not a delegate type

**The code is:**

```
private void backgroundWorker3_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
  HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmlDocument = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
  string text = this.textBox5.Text;
  htmlDocument.LoadHtml(text);
  HtmlNodeCollection htmlNodeCollection = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img/@alt");
  int num1 = 0;
  int k = 0;
  if (htmlNodeCollection == null || this.backgroundWorker3.CancellationPending)
    return;
  string links = "";
  foreach (HtmlNode htmlNode in (IEnumerable<HtmlNode>) htmlNodeCollection)
  {
    HtmlNode aTag = htmlNode;
    int num2 = int.Parse(this.textBox7.Text);
    this._busy.WaitOne(-1);
    if (!this.backgroundWorker3.CancellationPending)
    {
      ++k;
      this.Invoke((Delegate) (() => this.richTextBox4.AppendText(k.ToString() + "." + Environment.NewLine + aTag.InnerHtml + aTag.Attributes["alt"].Value + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine)));
      ++num1;
    }
    this.Invoke((Delegate) (closure_0 ?? (closure_0 = (Action) (() => links = this.richTextBox4.Text + Environment.NewLine))));
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(this.textBox2.Text + "/Descriptions.txt", links);
    if (num1 == num2)
    {
      this.backgroundWorker3.CancelAsync();
      if (!this.backgroundWorker3.CancellationPending)
        this._busy.Reset();
    }
  }
}
```

[Here is screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75fZ3.png)

Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is useless code:

```
this.Invoke((Delegate) (closure_0 ?? (closure_0 = (Action) (() => links = this.richTextBox4.Text + Environment.NewLine))));
```

You can safely replace it with:

```
this.Invoke(new Action(() => { links = this.richTextBox4.Text + Environment.NewLine; }));
```

Your first problem is that there is no variable or class field named `closure_0`, within the code you've shown.

Secondly, your syntax for creating and invoking an action on the UI is complicated and wrong, use the above simpler approach.

Comment: thankyou so much, i am newbie in c# I lost my very old source code, so i decompile my program with jetbrain dotpeek. I don't really understand some missing code. And now you fix my problem, Once again, thank you,